# Comparing two Byte Arrays byte by byte and return there difference?

Tags: c#, arrays

Well what i need to do is compare two byte arrays byte by byte and return there difference in int so then I'll use them in a progress bar.

But I don't have a single idea how could i do this. just give me a pseudo code. or some sort of explanation It will be helpful for me

Comment: each array should represent an integer value ? Not sure to understand.

Comment: difference... ? what do you mean by `difference`? like `50-20` 30 is the difference... if it's byte by byte difference then how can it be returned by an int?

Comment: Difference could be like in byte1 first byte matches the byte2 first byte. then it will make count 1 and so on. At the end for the sake of argument count will be like 20-30 so the difference between both of these arrays are 20-30

Comment: oh.. and will the array lengths be same all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a count of the number of differences try this

```
            byte[] array1 = new byte[2];
            byte[] array2 = new byte[2];

            int diff = array1.Where((x, i) => x != array2[i]).Count();
```